# query to fetch records and their rank in the DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds usernames and results.
When a user insert his results to the DB, I want to execute a query that will return 
the top X results ( with their rank in the db) and will also get that user result 
and his rank in the DB. 
the result should be like this:

1   playername      4500

2   otherplayer     4100

3   anotherone      3900
...

134 current player 140

I have tried a query with union, but then I didnt get the current player rank.
ideas anyone?

The DB is MYSQL.

10x alot and have agreat weekend :)

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried:

(select substr(first_name,1,10) as first_name, result 
        FROM top_scores ts
        WHERE result_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        LIMIT 10)
        union
(select substr(first_name,1,10) as first_name, result 
        FROM top_scores ts
        where first_name='XXX' and result=3030);

Comment: It's hard to answer something like this when you don't know what the tables look like. Can you post the two tables you are trying to `UNION`?

Comment: Is there a strong reason to be just "one query" in there?

Comment: I have added extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET X = 0;

SELECT @X:=@X+1 AS rank, username, result
FROM myTable
ORDER BY result DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

---

Re your comment:

How about this:

```
SET X = 0;

SELECT ranked.* 
FROM (
    SELECT @X:=@X+1 AS rank, username, result
    FROM myTable
    ORDER BY result DESC
) AS ranked
WHERE ranked.rank <= 10 OR username = 'current';
```

Comment: But what if the current player rank is 150? I want to get the top X results and the current player result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I am reading here:

Your table structure is:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| result | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table Data looks like:

```
+---------+--------+
| name    | result |
+---------+--------+
| Player1 |   4500 |
| Player2 |   4100 |
| Player3 |   3900 |
| Player4 |   3800 |
| Player5 |   3700 |
| Player6 |   3600 |
| Player7 |   3500 |
| Player8 |   3400 |
+---------+--------+
```

You want a result set to look like this:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| rank | name    | result |
+------+---------+--------+
|    1 | Player1 |   4500 |
|    2 | Player2 |   4100 |
|    3 | Player3 |   3900 |
|    4 | Player4 |   3800 |
|    5 | Player5 |   3700 |
|    6 | Player6 |   3600 |
|    7 | Player7 |   3500 |
|    8 | Player8 |   3400 |
+------+---------+--------+
```

SQL:

```
 set @rank = 0;
 select 
top_scores.* 
 from 
 (select ranks.* from (select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, name, result from ranks) ranks) top_scores
where 
top_scores.rank <= 5
or (top_scores.result = 3400 and name ='Player8');
```

That will do what you want it to do

Comment: That will get me the top 10 records, I need to get the current player rank as well.

Comment: You are wanting your result set to list the top x ranked players and then the selected player's information as well ?

Comment: The problem is I dont have rank column, it is something I have to calculate by the result.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your table has the following columns:

```
playername 
score
calculated_rank
```

your query should look something like:

```
select calculated_rank,playername, score 
from tablename 
order by calculated_rank limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have PRIMARY KEY on this table. If you don't, just create one. My table structure (because you didn't supply your own) is like this:

```
id          INTEGER
result      INTEGER
first_name  VARCHAR
```

SQL query should be like that:

```
SELECT @i := @i+1 AS position, first_name, result FROM top_scores, (SELECT @i := 0) t ORDER BY result DESC LIMIT 10 UNION
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM top_scores t2 WHERE t2.result > t1.result AND t2.id > t1.id) AS position, first_name, result FROM top_scores t1 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I added additional condition into subquery ("AND t2.id > t1.id") to prevent multiple people with same result having same position.

EDIT: If you have some login system, it would be better to save userid with result and get current user result using it.

Comment: I`m getting the following error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I've fixed the problem. "t" is necessary :)